# How to make Vaadin Panels extend across the whole page?

Tags: vaadin

How do I make my panels extend the full width across the page and not just to where their components stop?

Comment: have you tried `setSizeFull()` (on all containers down to the panel)? other please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

As also cfrick suggested, use `setSizeFull()`, if your component is nested inside other layouts/components, you need to set all of them to full size as follows.

```
VerticalLayout panelWrapper = new VerticalLayout();
Panel yourPanel = new Panel();
panelWrapper.addComponent(yourPanel);
yourPanel.setSizeFull();
panelWrapper.setSizeFull();
```

If you have more parent components, you need to `setSizeFull()` all of them back to the UI root.